# Codename One - Do something on orientation change

Tags: codenameone

I have a `TableLayout` with some width constraints. I want the constraints to be different when the orientation of the device changes. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an orientation listener and on orientation change event remove all the components then re-add them. I would suggest using `animateLayout()` to make that appear smoother. You can attach an orientation listener to your parent form using `addOrientationListener()`.

Comment: Is there any way to get the orientation on the change, if the device is in landscape mode it should display things differently than if the device is in portrait mode.

Comment: Figured it out it's `Display.getInstance().isPortrait();` thanks for the reply!